# Elasticsearch is pointing to only one node on the server

Tags: mac-osx, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 6.4.0 and it's working fine, except that there are 3 nodes on the server but my service points only to one node. This causes a slowdown in performance.

How can I point my service to all nodes on the server?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Not sure what difference this will make, but as of a week ago version 7.3.2 of Elasticsearch is available - so potentially upgrading to that may make a difference.

Comment: need to use version 6.4.0 of Elasticseach, and routing on all of nodes.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how well your question will go on this site, as I don't imagine there'll be a lot of Elasticsearch users here. We'll give it a couple of days (although the weekend isn't usually the best time) and if we have no joy it may be worth considering migrating this question to another one of the sites in the [SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name). In the meantime, you may want to try contacting the developers directly for support?